# Throttling Jenkins pipeline builds but still allow manually starting builds when throttled

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, throttling

How do you throttle Jenkins pipeline build so the queue doesn't get filled with multiple pipeline jobs but still allow someone to force start a build if they need it?

Currently, the throttle builds property will prevent the job from starting at all (during the throttling period) through the jenkins web interface.  "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" or "Quiet Period" may be a better option but I cannot set that in the Jenkinsfile.